# Detect if focusin event comes after a pop up is being closed with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Im detecting the focusin and focusout event on an element. This element has links that open a new window. If you open a window and then close it, then your focus returns to the element.

I need to distinguish when the focusin event is firing after a pop up window has been closed as opposed to when its normally focused on the page. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: a user with 2k reputation asking question without code :o

Comment: `$('elementID').focus(function(){..}).blur(function(){...});` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: I need to differentiate when the focus event comes from closing a pop up rather than just normally focusing on different elements on the page.